# Passing lightning-input time value from LWC to APEX taking timezone into acount

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, timezone, time

I'm having trouble passing a time (not datetime, not date) from custom LWC to APEX and saving it taking the user time zone into account. Before giving the details, I'd like to say that I checked [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/328329/timezone-conversion-after-passing-value-from-lwc-to-apex), [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/352/date-input-taking-into-account-users-time-zone-offset), [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/328204/datetime-value-change-when-passing-to-apex-from-lwc), [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/395769/how-to-replace-time-part-of-datetime-input-by-value-from-time-input) and [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/316173/lightning-input-type-date-time-picks-incorrect-time-value), but I couldn't solve my issue.

With that out of the way, my scenario is the following:

The LWC has a `<lightning-input type="time"></lightning-input>`. The value for this input comes from an APEX controller, the value is an Integer that represents the time in milliseconds, and, from what I understand at least, the time zone is the GMT (UTC). Before setting the value for the input to use, I format the value with JS (simplified):

```
import { api, LightningElement } from "lwc";
import LOCALE from "@salesforce/i18n/locale";
import TIME_ZONE from "@salesforce/i18n/timeZone";

export default class MyLWC extends LightningElement {
    _timeValue;
    @api set timeValue(value) { // the value here is milliseconds (integer)
        this._timeValue = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(LOCALE, {
            hour: "2-digit",
            minute: "2-digit",
            timeZone: TIME_ZONE,
        }).format(new Date(value));
    }
    get timeValue() {
        return this._timeValue;
    }
}
```

The HTML part:

```
<template>
    <lightning-input type="time" value={timeValue}></lightning-input>
</template>
```

Up to this point, things work as they should. My issue begins when the user changes the value. When changing the time from, say, 11:00 to 13:00, the input value becomes a string `'13:00:00.000'`. If I try to send the value as is to the APEX controller for saving in my SObject, I receive an error stating that it was not possible to read the values for the SObject (I'll list the complete JSON at the end). My first attempt to solve the problem was:

```
parseTimeValueToApex(value) {
    const splittedTime = value.split(':') // [hh, mm, ss.zzz]

    const parsedTime = new Date(`1970-01-01 ${splittedTime[0]}:${splittedTime[1]}`).getTime();

    return parsedTime;
}
```

Then I send it to the APEX controller and it gets saved. The data sent is as below:

```
{
    "RelatorioEletronico__c": "a19HZ00000028SvYAI", // parentRecordId
    "Id": "a1AHZ0000002DkL2AU",
    "ChegadaCliente__c": 1800000, // time field
    "Data__c": "2023-05-16", // date field
    "FimIntervalo1__c": 1800000, // time field
    "InicioIntervalo1__c": 1800000, // time field
    "Intervalo1__c": 1800000, // time field
    "KmFinalInformado__c": 90711, // number field
    "KmInicialInformado__c": 90701, // number field
    "Maquina_Trabalhando__c": "Sim", // picklist field
    "RetornoCliente__c": 1800000, // time field
    "SaidaCliente__c": 1800000, // time field
    "SaidaParaCliente__c": 1800000, // time field
    "sobjectType": "RelatorioHoras__c" // added for apex identification and proper interpretation
}
```

The APEX controller method is as follows:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static void updateTimeReport(RelatorioHoras__c timeReport){
    try {
        update timeReport;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

It all works, the problem is APEX save the time as UTC, so when I get the time back in the LWC and format it is not the same time the user inputed.

The second and last attempt I tried was to add/subtract the timezone offset before updating the record. For doing it, I created a wrapper class that receives the time fields as a string like `'13:00:00.000'`.

```
public class TimeReportWrapper {
    @AuraEnabled
    public Id Id { get; set; }
    @AuraEnabled
    public String ChegadaCliente { get; set; }
    @AuraEnabled
    public Date Data { get; set; }
    @AuraEnabled
    public String FimIntervalo1 { get; set; }
    @AuraEnabled
    public String FimIntervalo2 { get; set; }
    @AuraEnabled
    public String FimIntervalo3 { get; set; }
    @AuraEnabled
    public String FimIntervalo4 { get; set; }
    @AuraEnabled
    public String InicioIntervalo1 { get; set; }
    @AuraEnabled
    public String InicioIntervalo2 { get; set; }
    @AuraEnabled
    public String InicioIntervalo3 { get; set; }
    @AuraEnabled
    public String InicioIntervalo4 { get; set; }
    @AuraEnabled
    public Decimal KmFinalInformado { get; set; }
    @AuraEnabled
    public Decimal KmInicialInformado { get; set; }
    @AuraEnabled
    public String Maquina_Trabalhando { get; set; }
    @AuraEnabled
    public String NomeTecnico { get; set; }
    @AuraEnabled
    public String RetornoCliente { get; set; }
    @AuraEnabled
    public String SaidaCliente { get; set; }
    @AuraEnabled
    public String SaidaParaCliente { get; set; }
    @AuraEnabled
    public Decimal TotalKM { get; set; }
    @AuraEnabled
    public Decimal TotalKMInformado { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have a method that instantiate a new RelatorioHoras__c (the SObject I'm having trouble with) and set the fields accordingly, I won't list it because it's very simple, but the time fields are parsed before being set.

```
private static Time parseTimeValue(String timeString) {
    if (timeString == null) {
        return null;
    }

    String[] splitted = timeString.split('[^0-9]');

    Integer msOffset = UserInfo.getTimeZone().getOffset(System.now());

    return Time.newInstance(Integer.valueOf(splitted[0]), Integer.valueOf(splitted[1]), 0, 0).addMilliseconds(msOffset * -1); // add or subtract the offset in an attempt to save the correct UTC time. Add when offset is negative and subtract otherwise.
    }
```

For users in Brazil time zone (GMT-3) it is working as expected, but for users in UK (GMT-0) and Germany (GMT+2 or +3) it saves one hour earlier and each time the user saves the record in the LWC (without changing anything) it substracts one hour for the time.

I'm two weeks into the issue and I can't solve it. Any help would be appreciated.

If further details are required, please let me know.

Regards,
Miguel Bohrz